# Joomla 3.0 custom video and image URL upload option

Tags: php, joomla3.0

i have a joomla 3.0 component for movies sales (PICSELL) but i want to add an option where i can choose to upload movies using (Custom URL to upload movie and Images) the component already has file manager where to upload movies,images,prices,movie type (zip file or flv) and i want to add an option to it so that ones i put the url it will call both video and image from my server due to uploading problems and internet connection problem by uploading from file manager.while adding the URL option other information should be same in the file manager.so the option button will be shown ontop of the file manager to choose between uploading via file manager or via URL
 how do i do that? what code will i use and where to use the code?

Answer (score 0):

You want load videos from upload file or url path

i see the documentation and using multiple site.

Its totally free

> General Video : Select when you upload video from your hard disk or
> through a direct video file path

I have suggest [yendif player](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/multimedia/multimedia-players/yendif-video-share)